# How to prove that the policy banner is showing up before the user credentials

Tags: terminal, catalina, security

I set up the classic company **policy banner** that a user must read and accept before is prompting to log in with the credentials.

The Security Department is asking me if there is a command line in terminal that I can run and the output of the command must show as proof that the policy banner is really showing up before the user log in.

Banner Path: `/etc/banner`

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: What is prof? and how would a command line tell if the screen is set up?

Comment: You may have to just show them that it is working under multiple login attempts.

Comment: That sounds like an odd request.  The way you prove a screen is being displayed is to actually display the screen.